# How to set up in ZPL so that the label goes out by 20 mm further (eject of additional 20 mm)?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I have a Zebra ZT230 label printer set to web sensoring mode. Unfortunately the material I try to print on is unstandarized (50mm width, 247,5mm length, with a big hole at the end of the label). Label stops just after the "hole" ends and I need to eject about 20-25mm of label to reach the end of the label. What command should I use in ZPL to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The front panel has a setting called tear off adjust. you can use the front panel to set that value so that the label is lined up properly after print.

Also there is a ZPL command ~TA that can be found on page 349 of this manual:
https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/13979l-010_ra.pdf